# Code Igniter Project Folder

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, directory

I have a code igniter project folder. Everything works fine.
But when i placed the project folder in another folder as a sub-folder, i get 404 Page Not Found for the Controller URLS i called.

For instance the CI url is http://localhost/library
Then i place it in another folder like : http://localhost/school/library

How do i solve this problem? I know its a directory problem.
Thank you.

.htaccess file :

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Structure of folder

```
    school/
          students/
          teachers/
          library/
                 application/
                 system/
                 assets/
                 index.php
                 .htaccess
```

The library folder is using code igniter frame work but the school folder which is the main folder is using no frame work.

Comment: Post your .htaccess file **in the question**

Comment: RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file in the **school** folder? also, did you change your `index_page` config?

Comment: There is no .htaccess in the school folder. I don't get the second part of the question.

Comment: I mean you need to set `index_page` to a blank value in **application/config/config.php**. This is really weird as you don't have to change the `index_page` in order for it to work. Is there anything else in your `.htaccess` file other than the content I gave you in the answer? is `mod_rewrite` enabled in your server? can you tell me the path you are trying to access that gives you the 404 error?

Comment: There is nothing else inside the .htaccess apart from what you mentioned. I am trying to access localhost/school/library/home/login.
But when i access it like this localhost/library/home/login.
It works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167033/discussion-between-mehdi-bounya-and-jayden).

Answer (score 1):

create a file named `.htaccess` and put this code in

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Inside the school folder or the Library folder? Because i already have an .htaccess file in the Library folder which is the CI folder. The School folder does not make use of CI framework

Comment: first time check if you have it in the main folder of you're project

Comment: Main folder does not make use of CI framework and hence no .htaccess file but the sub folder Library has an .htaccess folder.

Comment: could you tell me the exact structure of you're project?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are pointing to an `index.php` that is in your root folder, change that by using `./index.php` instead.

Create a `.htaccess` file in your project folder with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L]
```

You see the `./` part means **Add the path to where .htaccess exists**

Comment: Can you update your question with your folders structure?

Comment: Just did. Please check.